# Is there a way for a spinner option to open another spinner?

Tags: android, eclipse, spinner, android-spinner

I want it where when someone clicks an option in a Spinner, it opens another spinner with more options. Also, is there a way for an "Other" option to open an EditText where someone can input their selection if theirs isn't available in the Spinner?

Example:

Spinner 1 has these options:

**iOS**

**Android**

And if they select **iOS**, another spinner comes up immediately where the options are all the iPhone versions. (i.e., titled "Which iPhone do you have?")

And if they select Android, it does the same thing, but with Android devices.

AND if their phone isn't on the second spinner, they type the model of their phone in.

How could I do this if I have the first spinner already in my code?

P.S., if needed, I can post the code for the first spinner, though it's pretty standard.

Comment: Launching a Dialog with the remaining options is not an option?

Comment: Not clear, but you can populate another spinnner based on the selection of the first spinnner.

Answer (score 0):

Basically build your second spinner programmatically depending on which option they choose.  I'd add "other" to each second spinner.  If they choose "other" then you can display the text box.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be useful to you.

Try this Code...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Spinner sp1,sp2;
ArrayAdapter<String> adp1,adp2;
List<String> l1,l2;
int pos;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    l1=new ArrayList<String>();

    l1.add("A");
    l1.add("B");

    sp1= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    sp2= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    adp1=new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,l1);
    adp1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    sp1.setAdapter(adp1);

    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pos=arg2;
            add();

        }

        private void add() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ""+pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            switch(pos)
            {
            case 0:
                l2= new ArrayList<String>();                    
                l2.add("A 1");
                l2.add("A 2");

                adp2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,l2);
                adp2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
                sp2.setAdapter(adp2);

                select();

                break;
            case 1:
                l2= new ArrayList<String>();                    
                l2.add("B 1");
                l2.add("B 2");

                adp2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,l2);
                adp2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
                sp2.setAdapter(adp2);

                select();

                break;
            }

        }

        private void select() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Test "+arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    }

}
```